# How to resolve this error : "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"?

Tags: ios, swift, api, sdwebimage

I am using this SDWebImage framework. And the error shows : "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)".

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFW9w.png)

```
let thumbImgaURL = URL(string: movie.movieThumbMailURL!)
self.imgMovie.sd_setImage(with: thumbImgaURL, placeholderImage:#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ic_video_Placeholder"), options: .cacheMemoryOnly) { (thumbImage, error,chache, imgURL) in
  if thumbImage != nil {
       self.imgMovie.image = thumbImage!
  }
  else {
       print("OK2")
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide the full, more human readable, message from the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your placeholder image `placeholderImage` not found  just set `placeholderImage` to nil or add image

```
let thumbImgaURL = URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFW9w.png")
    self.imgMovie.sd_setImage(with: thumbImgaURL, placeholderImage:nil, options: .cacheMemoryOnly) { (thumbImage, error,chache, imgURL) in
        if thumbImage != nil {
            self.imgMovie.image = thumbImage!
        }
        else {
            print("OK2")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to fix the placeholder image than simply show no placeholder?

Comment: ok, good , but just want to show him that i tested on my xcode

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should handling your URL definition:

```
if let url = URL(string: movie.movieThumbMailURL){
   // put your code here
}
```

Then , about the line:

```
self.imgMovie.sd_setImage(with ...
```

check if your Assets folder is present to the build phases/copy bundle resources folder otherwise your crash could be happened 'cause the system didn't find the file **Ic_video_Placeholder**